# How to build missing PHP 5.3 extensions on CentOS 5.6

Tags: php, centos, web-server

I've created a fresh installation of CentOS 5.6, and installed PHP 5.3 using the `php53-*` packages from the CentOS repository. Specifically, I've got:

- php53
- php53-cli
- php53-common
- php53-devel
- php53-mysql
- php53-pdo
- php53-xml

However, I also need to install the `mcrypt` and `apc` extensions for my application. CentOS has a pre-built `php-mcrypt` package, but there is no equivalent `php53-mcrypt`. The installation of APC requires `pecl` which I would normally install (for 5.1) with the `php-pear` package, but likewise there doesn't seem to be a `php53-pear` package.

How do I build these?

**Edit**
It looks like the `php-pear` package works with `php53`, so I managed to get APC installed properly. I still have a problem with `mcrypt` because it's not installable via pecl; it's only part of the core PHP build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile and install manually only the mcrypt extension. This is what I did in my CentOS 5.6 VPS:

First install some required packages:

```
yum install php53-devel libmcrypt-devel gcc gcc-c++
```

Then download the php 5.3.6 source code from php.net and unpack it:

```
wget http://mx2.php.net/get/php-5.3.6.tar.bz2/from/us3.php.net/mirror
tar xvjf php-5.3.6.tar.bz2
```

*(Please note that the download link will change with every subsequent PHP release.)*

Go to the directory with the mcrypt extension source code and compile:

```
cd php-5.3.6/ext/mcrypt/
phpize
aclocal
./configure
make
```

Then install:

```
make install
```

Create the configuration file for PHP **/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini** containing:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Create a file with phpinfo just to check if the extension was loaded:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the php-pear package:

This problem should be solved with RHEL in order to be solved in CentOS, here is the bug report about that problem:
[PHP53 Lacks php53-pear](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=673521)

Install the older php-pear via `yum install php-pear` and than run the following commands:

```
pear upgrade --force Console_Getopt
pear upgrade --force pear
pear upgrade-all
```

(It seems that these commands will solve the issue, it worked for *labradort* from the linked bug report and it worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get php53-mcrypt and a few other missing packages by adding the EPEL repository from http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL to your system.

Answer (score 0):

install php53-mcrypt from the redhad/fedora repo for version5, has an epl5 version :)

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=php53-mcrypt&srodzaj=3

Comment: Answers that are little more than links aren't good answers. Can you add some more explanation.